# NumPy behavior - manipulating array changes original data?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a small array `data` that undergoes a reshape and a copy

```
data = np.array([77, 115, 137, 89, 42, 107, 54, 256])

subset = data[:4].reshape(2,2)

newdata = data[4:].copy()

subset[-1,-1] = 0

newdata[1] = 0

print(data)
print(subset)
print(newdata)
```

Seems pretty simple. My assumption for this is that I would get the following outputs

```
data = array([ 77, 115, 137, 89, 42, 107, 54, 256])

subset = array([[ 77, 115],
                [137, 0]])

newdata = array([ 42, 0, 54, 256])
```

I was correct for subset and newdata, but not `data` itself, which now outputs

```
data = np.array([77, 115, 137, 0, 42, 107, 54, 256])
```

The original `data` array has been modified from what looks like the reshape and copy and changing the 89 to 0

Any help on why and how these methods do in fact modify the original array is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can read [copies and views](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html) in the official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subset` is not a copy but a *view* of `data`. Thus any change on `subset` is a change on `data` too.

Comment: Basic indexing as with `[:4]` produces a view.  `reshape` usually produces a view as well.  But sometimes the combination produces a copy.  In this case is was still a view, but we need to be careful.  There have a lot of SO about testing whether something is indeed a view or not.

Answer (score 1):

As @Julien point out, you are dragging the variable anytime you make changes based on `data`. So to keep your variable untouched, you can use deepcopy:

```
import copy

data = np.array([77, 115, 137, 89, 42, 107, 54, 256])
data2 = copy.deepcopy(data)
subset = data[:4].reshape(2,2)
newdata = data[4:].copy()
subset[-1,-1] = 0
newdata[1] = 0

print(data) # [ 77 115 137   0  42 107  54 256]
print(data2) # [ 77 115 137  89  42 107  54 256]
```

Comment: You don't need `deepcopy` with arrays - unless it is object dtype.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, I just point out a way to solve the issue of the OP. You are welcome to post your own solution as well. Regards.

Comment: `data2 = data.copy()` is enough.